# Binding to element in WPF: can the Path expression do math?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to bind a control to the parent's Height/width property using `ElementName` and a Path. However, I don't want to bind to the actual height, but to exactly half the height.
Can the `Path` expression do the math?

e.g. `Path={ActualHeight/2}`

I couldn't find a way to do that. IS there any other clever approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a note: Depending on your scenario, a simple star-sized [Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx) might also do the job. Often, people use a lot of bindings to make their UI dynamically sized, although it is much easier to do so with a Grid. However, I do not know your exact requirements, so maybe you really need an IValueConverter as pointed out by ArsenMkrt below.

Comment: In my case it was a RadiusX and RaduisY property that needed to be half the height/width of the parent element (which is a grid). Thanks for the hint!

Comment: CalcBinding produces so much nicer code than other solutions! Check out Alex141 answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No it can't you should use [binding converters](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-binding-converters)

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
public object Convert(object value, Type  targetType,
      object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
      return (int)value/2;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
      object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Value converters exist solely for this purpose - to transform the value between the source and target - http://www.wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html. Or if that is too much, you could declare a new get-only property HalfOfActualHeight if that is an option.

Comment: It seems this is exactly what I need, even if the task is so trivial. Thanks!

Answer (score 44):

I use a `MathConverter` to do math in my XAML bindings.The converter code can be found [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/the-math-converter/) and it is used like this:

```
Height="{Binding ElementName=RootWindow, Path=ActualHeight,
                 Converter={StaticResource MathConverter},
                 ConverterParameter=@VALUE/2}"
```

It will also handle more advanced math equations like

```
Height="{Binding ElementName=RootWindow, Path=ActualHeight,
                Converter={StaticResource MathConverter},
                ConverterParameter=((@VALUE-200)*.3)}"
```

Answer (score 9):

No, standart binding doesn't support expressions in Path. But you can look at my project [CalcBinding](https://github.com/Alex141/CalcBinding), which was developed specially to resolve this problem and some others. Say, you can write something like:

```
<Button Content="{c:Binding ElementName=grid, Path=ActualWidth+Height}"/>
```

or

```
<Label Content="{c:Binding A+B+C }" />
```

or

```
<Button Visibility="{c:Binding IsChecked, FalseToVisibility=Hidden}" />
```

where A, B, C, IsChecked - properties of viewModel and it will work properly

Goodluck!

Comment: Cool! Tried this, works without problem, code is more readable and shorter, no stupid converters lying around in files!

Comment: You need to add a namespace prefix xmlns:c="clr-namespace:CalcBinding;assembly=CalcBinding". See the example https://github.com/Alex141/CalcBinding/blob/master/WpfExample/SecondPage.xaml

Answer (score 4):

@Rachel's MathConverter worked great for me, however I switched out the expression parsing and just left that bit to NCalc.  That way I didn't have to worry about operator precedence.

```
using NCalc;

using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace MyProject.Utilities.Converters
{
    public class MathConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo     culture)
        {
            // Parse value into equation and remove spaces
            string expressionString = parameter as string;
            expressionString = expressionString.Replace(" ", "");
            expressionString = expressionString.Replace("@VALUE", value.ToString());

            return new Expression(expressionString).Evaluate();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, when using NCalc, every expression is cached internally.  Since this entails working with dynamic data-bound values, I'd suggest throwing `EvaluateOptions.NoCache` as the second parameter to the `Expression` constructor.  That way you aren't consuming so much memory.

Comment: It might improve memory consumption since the parsed logical expression isn't kept in each Expression object, but I think the performance would take a hit.  Each time Evaluate() is called, you need to compile the expression from the original string.  There's no documentation on the site (https://ncalc.codeplex.com/), I'm just going from what I see in the code. (https://ncalc.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Evaluant.Calculator/Expression.cs)

Comment: Certainly it *could* drain performance.  The benefit of caching is only applicable if the expression is being frequently reused.  In my case, I bound to a `double` property which was generating a new expression each time I changed the value, and seldom reusing previous expressions.  It's a time-space trade-off and depends on the application.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at my `MathConverter` project. It allows for very advanced expressions, including string formatting.

In particular, your expression would be handled as such:

```
Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ConverterParameter=x/2, Converter={StaticResource math}}"
```

There are loads of examples, as well as a basic introduction of how to use it on the [project's homepage](https://github.com/hexinnovation/MathConverter).