# How to set width with simple math to an element?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have two elements like this:

```
<Button width="300" Name="SomeButton">
<Button Width="..?.." Name="Button2">
```

And I need the Button2 to have same width as the SomeButton minus 100. So if SomeButton width is  400, Button2 width will be 300.

Is there any xaml way to achieve this?

Comment: can you add it to your view model?

Comment: It's just an empty window with a grid which contains those two buttons.

Comment: Use `IValueConverter` for arithmetic operations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binding to element in WPF: can the Path expression do math?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757153/binding-to-element-in-wpf-can-the-path-expression-do-math)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue as you were having and I couuldn't think of a straight forward way to do it in XAML. You could always do it in the code-behind in your constructor though if you really need the width to be exactly 100 less.

If you want a XAML solution then your best bet is to define a grid and mess with the ColumnDefinition width attributes. Like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Name="SomeButton"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Name="Button2"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the width to a property in your code behind or View Model. Set Button2 width according to that property - 100.

```
<Button width="{Binding ButtonWidth}" Name="SomeButton">
<Button Width="{Binding ButtonWidth2}" Name="Button2">
```

In your Code Behind:

```
public int ButtonWidth { get { return 300; } } //just a bad example
```

But your other button:

```
public int ButtonWidth2 { get { return ButtonWidth - 100 ; } } //just a bad example
```

Make your properties notifiable.

Comment: Don't like. IValueConverter is made for this sort of issues